# How I can change structure of multiple arrays to array objects Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, data-structures, javascript-objects

(Variable file contains array of URL .json files). One file in subdirectories contains:

```
[ {"name": "John"} ]
```

Then I get common file get.json who contains all files from subdirectories in structure (yeap, I know it's not a valid JSON):

```
[ {"name": "John"} ]
[ {"name": "Sergei"} ]
```

I want get this file in this structure:

```
[ {name: "John"}, {name: "Sergei"} ]
```

**My code**

```
recursive(`${dirPath}`, ['delete.json', 'put.json'], function (err, file) {

  const write = fs.createWriteStream(`${dirPath}/get.json`);

  file.forEach(item => {
    fs.createReadStream(item).pipe(write);
  })

  write.on('finish', () => {
    fs.createReadStream(`${dirPath}/get.json`).pipe(res);
  })

});
```

Comment: `[ {name: "John"}] [ {name: "Sergei"}]` is not valid JSON. Is your sample data wrong, or are you asking how to parse this non-standard file format?

Comment: `[ {name: "John"}] [ {name: "Sergei"}]` - you claim this is JSON ... it isn't even close to JSON - if it were JSON, it'd look like `[[ {"name": "John"}],[ {"name": "Sergei"}]]` or `[ {"name": "John"}, {"name": "Sergei"} ]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Yeap, it's not valid JSON. One file in subbdirectory contains code as:
[ { name: "John} ], and when i I read all files and push them data in new, I get not valid JSON. How i can collect all this arrays in valid array objects?

Comment: **Read line by line:** parse each string/line to js object using the function `JSON.parse`, then get the object in index `0` and finally push it into an array.

Comment: Thx, but how I can read file line by line and select all objects in file?

Comment: Check out Node's `readline` module.  Alternatively, you might be able to take the text and do a `.split("\n")`.

Comment: @OP see if the answer works for you

Comment: posting the solution here https://repl.it/@caub/BarrenNegligibleExperiment because reviewers like @ddmps are not making sense

Answer (score 1):

One day from my life left with this task, done!

```
recursive(`${dirPath}`, ['delete.json', 'put.json'], function (err, file) {

  const write = fs.createWriteStream(`${dirPath}/get.json`);

  const usersArr = [];

  let readStream;

  file.forEach(item => {
    readStream = fs.createReadStream(item);
    readStream.on("data", (data) => {
      JSON.parse(data).map(item => usersArr.push(item));
    });
  })

  readStream.on("end", (data) => {
    write.write(JSON.stringify(usersArr, null, " "), () => {
      console.log('Completed');
    });

    fs.createReadStream(`${dirPath}/get.json`).pipe(res)
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = data.split('\n')
  .map(nameArrayString => (JSON.parse(nameArrayString)[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.